# If the PHP variable change, update div by using Ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I want to update a div by via Ajax if a php variable changes. My setup looks like this:

I'm using 2 files:

**index.php** (displays the div that needs updating):

```html
<?php include('variables.php?>                                           
<div id="apples">
Apples: <php echo "$applescount"; ?> 
</div>

<div id="oranges">                                                  
Oranges: <php echo "$orangescount"; ?>                                         
</div>
```

**variables.php** (where the variables are defined)

```html
$applescount = 2 (ex: value obtained  from db)
$orangescount = 3 (ex: value obtained from db)
```

I need a simple jQuery function that checks if the variables (`$applescount` or `$orangescount`) change and then updates the divs (apples and oranges respectively).

Comment: What is causing the variables to change?

Comment: The variables are counting the rows in db by using mysqli_num_rows function.

Comment: So you are trying to create a script that periodically polls the DB to see if it has changed?

Comment: A php variable can't change once the page is done loading

Comment: You may want to do "polling" for the state of your database. But this is very inefficient. It is not trivial to sync your client with your remote database. A webservice is a nice way of doing this by using push messages. I did it with ratchets beautiful php Implementation of the websocket protocol.

Comment: Yes, I want to see if my DB change, I know that polling is not efficient but at the moment is the only solution i found in order to solve my problem.

Comment: I think you want to compare the values obtained from db to the variables in variables .php if and display the value instead of 2 and 3 , which are the main values so include variables.php in the page that you called with ajax then use if statement to create array and add new apples and oranges values if the value not equal to the original one and with jquery functions update the div

Answer (score 0):

Create an javascript interval that makes an AJAX request every few seconds to your back end, return the results as JSON. Parse the JSON in the front end to update to user interface.

Might want to consider making this using javascripts new 'promise' system.

PHP does not allow two-way data binding without polling.

You could consider creating a socket connection that 'connects' to something on your backend, then there might be a library that can integrate with your database to notify of certain values changing, not sure if this would be with PHP though.

Something like this:

```
 function doPoll(){
$.post('ajax/test.html', function(data) {
    alert(data);  // process results here
    setTimeout(doPoll,5000);
});
}
```

Comment: Updated my answer with a doPoll function. Call this code to start the loop, and it will call itself. You can change the post/get as well as the target file. The data will be the response you parse to update your web page.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
 $.post('update.php', function(response)    { 
    $('#apples').text(response.apples);
    $('#oranges').text(response.oranges);
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

While this seems to be on the right track... you should use a medium PHP handler to handle whatever you wish to do with the data.

This is the general direction (you need jquery to be loaded)

### HTML

```
Apples : <span id="apples"></span>
Oranges : <span id="oranges"></span>
```

### JS

```
$.post('handler.php',function(data){
   $('#apples').html(data.apples);  
   $('#oranges').html(data.oranges);
})
```

### PHP - handler.php

```
<?php

// get from db etc...
$apples = get_from_db();
$oranges = get_from_db();

echo json_encode([
   "apples" => $apples,
   "oranges" => $oranges
]);

?>
```

The JS will call PHP and the response should come back in an object.
if you wish a non-jquery version you should look into youmightnotneedjquery.com